# Splitting information from a cell

Tags: formatting, excel-2010, concatenation, currency, text-to-column

My sheet contains three types of cells:

- 5off
- 50off
- 550off

What they should read is:

- $5.00 Off
- $0.50 Off
- $5.50 Off

I've been fighting with Text-to-Columns and =concat for a while and am trying to get this to work as easily as possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering what's the rule of the conversion for example the first figure is

> 5off => "$5.00 Off" > split number, add decimal, upper the O in off, concatenate

However in number two the rules are a little different

> 50off => "$0.50 Off" > split number, make the number decimal, concatenate

Based on those limited information I will suggest you to break down your problem to simpler form:
See image below, the top is the result, bottom is the formula used. There might be simpler way though.

[image]

Hope this help